# running './gradlew' on gate folder throws error

Tags: spinnaker

I am trying to build spinnaker gate by cloning it from git. When i am running `./gradlew` from inside the gate folder, I am getting the below error

---

```
error: error reading /home/~/gate/gate-core/build/libs/gate-core-4.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar; invalid header field
Note: /home/~/gate/gate-web/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/gate/services/appengine/StorageAccountService.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
startup failed:
/home/~/gate/gate-web/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/gate/config/GateConfig.groovy: 31: unable to resolve class com.netflix.spinnaker.gate.retrofit.Slf4jRetrofitLogger
 @ line 31, column 1.
   import com.netflix.spinnaker.gate.retrofit.Slf4jRetrofitLogger
   ^

/home/~/gate/gate-web/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/gate/config/GateConfig.groovy: 33: unable to resolve class com.netflix.spinnaker.gate.services.internal.ClouddriverService
 @ line 33, column 1.
   import com.netflix.spinnaker.gate.services.internal.ClouddriverService
   ^
.
.
.
.
71 errors

:gate-web:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gate-web:compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
---------------------------------------------
```

Need help on the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I just tried the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/spinnaker/gate.git
cd gate
./gradlew
```

And everything compiled and Gate started as expected (using JDK8u111). Are you sure you didn't change anything? Perhaps try a fresh clone.